# SQL: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'" when comparing two dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

The following is my MS sql-server statement, which is used in my C# Windows application.  As the title suggests, it selects all product numbers that are between the Textbox dates.  I'm fairly inexperienced with SQL, so my attempt may be an atrocity.  SQL seems to think so.

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM HISTORY ORDER BY productNumber WHERE (@strt_date >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(KHDate1Box.Text) + "' and @end_date <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(KHDate2Box.Text) + "')";
```

SQL error message:  "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'."

Comment: You should post what the _value_ of `strSQL` is after it is created there.  The error you're getting is after you've created that query, so we need to see what the query looks like.

Comment: From your SQL syntax, it looks like your date columns are named @ strt_date and @ end_date. I doubt this is right because usually any name starting with @ means it is a locally declared variable. If your date columns are named strt_date and end_date, then remove the @ symbols and that should be one error out of the way. Also, I'm used to seeing the ORDER BY clause after the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM HISTORY ORDER BY productNumber WHERE (@strt_date >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(KHDate1Box.Text) + "' and @end_date <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(KHDate2Box.Text) + "')";
```

That's because the WHERE clause should come *before* `ORDER BY`

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM HISTORY WHERE (@strt_date >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(KHDate1Box.Text) + "' and @end_date <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(KHDate2Box.Text) + "' ORDER BY productNumber)"  ;
```

Comment: It's always the little things that cause the biggest problems.  I could only select one as the answer, but you and ElVieejo both nailed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
"    SELECT * FROM HISTORY 
    WHERE (@strt_date >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(KHDate1Box.Text) + "' and @end_date <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(KHDate2Box.Text) + "')
    ORDER BY productNumber "
```

the order by goes after the where clause

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you are using `@strt_date` and `@end_date` (which are T-SQL variables) as column names. Also, the `ORDER BY` clause should be *after* the `WHERE` clause.

---

As an aside, there are a variety of reasons why you should *not* code a query in this way. Google "SQL Injection" for a very eye opening security issue.

Instead use parameterized queries. They are safer and less prone to syntax errors caused by invalid characters in the value fields.

http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06

Answer (score 1):

If it's only dates, there's not much chance of SQL injection especially if you validate it.

If you must pass a date as string to SQL Server, it should be in the unambiguous YYYYMMDD format.  But I'd also add the validation of the input as date.

Have this before that statement

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Then, change it to

```
string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM HISTORY ORDER BY productNumber WHERE (@strt_date >= '" +
  DateTime.ParseExact(KHDate1Box.Text, "d", provider).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
  + "' and @end_date <= '" +
  DateTime.ParseExact(KHDate2Box.Text, "d", provider).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "')";
```

Catch errors from failing to parse the date.

Reference: I used "d" but here's the list of [Standard Datetime Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)